# How to add another variable to a script

Tags: javascript, datejs

I've having trouble trying to get the following script to work correctly. I'm trying to add another variable to a script, which I've kind of hacked together with my lack of programming knowledge! However it doesn't seem to work when I add the variable called extraDate. It works without it so I must be getting something wrong somewhere.

Could anyone please point out what the problem is?

Thanks for any help.

**Output:**
Using a span with id="extraDate", id="fromDate" and id="toDate"

**Script:**
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js

**Full code**

```
var fromDate = Date.today().addDays(1);
        if (fromDate.is().saturday() || fromDate.is().sunday()) { 
          fromDate = fromDate.next().monday();
        }
        var toDate = Date.today().addDays(2);
        if (toDate.is().saturday()) { 
          toDate = toDate.next().monday();
        }
        else if (toDate.is().monday()) { 
          toDate = toDate.next().tuesday();
        }
        else if (toDate.is().sunday()) { 
          toDate = toDate.next().tuesday();
        }
        var extraDate = Date.today().addDays(4);
        if (extraDate.is().saturday() || extraDate.is().sunday()) { 
          extraDate = extraDate.next().monday();
        }
        document.getElementById('fromDate').innerHTML = fromDate.toString('dddd dS MMMM');
        document.getElementById('toDate').innerHTML = toDate.toString('dddd dS MMMM');
        document.getElementById('extraDate').innerHTML = extraDate.toString('dddd dS MMMM');
```

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to work"? Does it throw an error or is extraDate a wrong value?

Comment: Are you using momentjs or something? If so mention it, or post complete code.

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` - the whole script, or just the `extraDate` part - if it's just the latter, do you have a html tag with `id="extraDate"`?

Comment: Sorry, it's just the extraDate part that doesn't work. No errors, just a blank space when I try and output. I'll update my original post with any additional scripts/code.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be something wrong with your HTML-Code, because in my example snippet your exact code works without any issues:

```js
var fromDate = Date.today().addDays(1);
if (fromDate.is().saturday() || fromDate.is().sunday()) { 
  fromDate = fromDate.next().monday();
}
var toDate = Date.today().addDays(2);
if (toDate.is().saturday()) { 
  toDate = toDate.next().monday();
}
else if (toDate.is().monday()) { 
  toDate = toDate.next().tuesday();
}
else if (toDate.is().sunday()) { 
  toDate = toDate.next().tuesday();
}
var extraDate = Date.today().addDays(4);
if (extraDate.is().saturday() || extraDate.is().sunday()) { 
  extraDate = extraDate.next().monday();
}
document.getElementById('fromDate').innerHTML = fromDate.toString('dddd dS MMMM');
document.getElementById('toDate').innerHTML = toDate.toString('dddd dS MMMM');
document.getElementById('extraDate').innerHTML = extraDate.toString('dddd dS MMMM');
```

```html
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/datejs/date.js"></script>
<p id="fromDate"></p>
<p id="toDate"></p>
<p id="extraDate"></p>
```

Comment: I've found what the problem is. For some reason, extraDate only outputs when id="fromDate" and id="toDate" are also present on the page. If I try and remove one or both of them, then id="extraDate" doesn't output anything.

Comment: because javascript exits the script, the time the error occurs.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Julian, I'll try and find a workaround.